# How to search multiple columns for unique text to input those unique rows into other sheet

Tags: vba, excel, unique, vlookup

I am not sure if my question is going to be regarding a macro in VBA or a VLOOKUP type of thing but I'll try my best to explain both.

I am trying to make a time sheet for people to enter their time spent working on various projects. It works well but I am trying to add a feature to separate the time spent at regular pay, overtime pay, or double time pay.

There are three sheets named **Time Log**, **Project List**, and **Timesheet**.

This is an image from **Time Log**:

[image: Time Log]

Employees enter the project name and project number and task is retrieved from **Project List** using VLOOKUP and then the employee enters the type of payment they receive for that work. Throughout the week, an employee may enter multiples of the same entries.

At the end of the week, they'll go to **Timesheet** and press a button I have attached to a macro which will retrieve the unique values from all the entries in the **Time Log**.

This is an image from **Timesheet**:

[image: Timesheet]

As you can see, I have made it work to find the unique project names but now I have run into an issue with the pay type that is entered. I am not sure how to have it draw a new entry for each unique project name *and* unique type.

Ideally, it would come out like this:
[image: Timesheet Ideal]

So what I have so far is my macro to search the **Time Log** for unique project names and put them into **Timesheet**:

```
Sub Input_Project_Names()
'
' Input_Project_Names Macro
'

' Clear Project Names
Worksheets("Timesheet").Range("A4:A50").ClearContents

'Advanced Filter from Time Log to Timesheet
    Sheets("Time Log").Range("A1").CurrentRegion.AdvancedFilter _
    Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
    CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Project List").Range("H1:H2"), _   
    CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A52"), _
    Unique:=True


End Sub
```

So this is where I am stuck... How do I modify the macro so that it looks for unique project names & types? And if I'm unable to do this, is there a way to use VLOOKUP or similar to do what I'm aiming for?

Big thanks for all help!

Comment: @pnuts, `Task` is not really important part of this question. The reason that is there is because projects are broken down into subcategories sometimes. So a certain project number may have several different tasks associated with it. These tasks do not change with how many hours an employee works on it.

Comment: Sounds like you could just copy all the data then use a remove duplicates function across all columns to get all unique entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `SortedList` object:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim sortedList As Object
    Set sortedList = CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    Dim cell As Range
    With Worksheets("Time Log") 'reference "Time Log" worksheet
        For Each cell In .Range("A2", .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) 'loop thorugh referenced sheet column A cells from row 2 down to last not empty one
            sortedList(cell.Value & "," & cell.Offset(, 3).Value) = cell.Resize(, 4).Value 'add current record to SortedList assigning "Project Name, Type" as ist key : it will do nothing if there's already a record with the same "Project Name" & "Type" key
        Next
    End With

    Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Time Sheet") ''reference "Time Sheet" worksheet
        For i = 0 To sortedList.Count - 1 'loop through Sorted List object items
            .cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(, 4).Value = sortedList.GetByIndex(i) 'write referenced sheet currently first empty row with current Sorted List item
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems like this is very close to working but unfortunately, it is repeating entries. See my image here: [Macro Result](https://i.imgur.com/rjXv3dn.png)

It's repeated Test 2, Regular 

Also, it has only included 1 entry for Test 3 and for Test 4 when there should be multiple.
Do you have any idea how to resolve this? It feels so close!!

Thank you!

Comment: I tested with data as shown in your question and it gave the exact results you wanted.

Comment: Hmm, I'll have to try and figure out what is wrong then.